# sudo broken. Unable to enter recovery mode to fix it

Tags: linux, command-line, sudo

I broke sudo when I wrongly edited a file in /etc/sudoers.d in vi(did not use visudo :-().

I [read](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-496494.html) that I could fix the same by rebooting into the 'Recovery Mode' by selecting the same from the grub menu.

However I'd earlier disabled the showing of the grub menu by editing /etc/default/grub. As a result I can't seem to go into recovery mode to fix my broken sudo.

How can I fix sudo now??

Comment: Well, at least you've just learned a valuable lesson.

Comment: @Rein, you betcha.. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> while booting, this will cause GRUB2 to show the boot menu. Next, after booting in Recovery mode, select Root shell. From there, you can edit your sudoers file by running `visudo` without sudo before it, you're root anyway ;)

Comment: This is useful to get hold of the grub2 boot menu too. Thanks.

Comment: To document an earlier answer which seems to have dissappeared by the time I tried it out(It worked for me).

"Grab a live CD. Boot into it. Mount your root file system. Fix sudo".